# Extracting data from db and constructing custom json

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table with sample data like this ->

```
column1 column2 
1       A
1       B
2       C
2       D
```

I want to create an endpoint that returns this ->

```
{
  "1" : {
    "column1": "1"
    "column2": [A, B]
  },
  "2" : {
    "column1": "2"
    "column2": [C, D]
  }
}
```

Whats the most efficient way to handle this?

My current approach:

1. Query `select * from table.`    `//this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql)`
2. Iterate and construct whatever required brute force.

   ```
   public Map formatData(List data) {
      // iterating over the list and logic to construct the required map.
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Some adjustments can be done on iterating over query results.

1. use `select distinct(c1) from t` only keys 

2. use `select distinct(c2) from t where t.c1=key` on iterate grabbing values directly 
from db, instead of iterating through all `*` and place conditions

```
public Map formatData(List keys) {
// iterating over the list and logic to construct the required map.
    for(String key:keys)
    {
         List values = query_2(key);
         map.put(key, values)
    }
}
```

It could be maybe faster since grabbing "final results" only from db(with out process from java code a raw_list), but it should be checked.